# Compile error trying to initialize Dictionary<T,U> with elements

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an Enum type e.g.

```
    enum MyEnum
    {
        V1,
        V2,
        V3
    }
```

And I want to add each element to a dictionary as Keys with additional data:

```
        Dictionary<MyEnum, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>(MyEnum.V1, "");
        };
```

But it cause compile error. However it works with a List.

```
List<MyEnum> list = new List<MyEnum>() { MyEnum.V1, MyEnum.V3 };
```

How can I make the Dictionary example work?

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer (found simply by googling `c# initialize dictionary`)

Comment: You are helping too much.  Use `{ MyEnum.V1, "" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>` Just use this:

```
        Dictionary<MyEnum, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>()
        {
            { MyEnum.V1, "" },
            { MyEnum.V2, "" }
        };
```